# Angular / AngularFire2 Firestore - Initialise Observable Collection

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, collections, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using material 2, and I'm trying to create data tables with pagination and sorting, so I need my collections to be observable, but I think I must be populating/initialising the arrays incorrectly in the controller.

I've been populating an 'expenses' array with data from an 'expenses' firestore collection using the method below, but this always says *"Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'any[]'"*...

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-expense-list',
  templateUrl: './expense-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./expense-list.component.scss']
})

export class ExpenseListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  tableColumns = [ 'id' ];

  expenses: any[];

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.expenses = this.db.collection('/expenses').valueChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

  }

  viewExpense(row) {
    console.log('viewExpense(' + row.id + '): ', row);
  }

}
```

How do I properly create an **observable** array that's populated with data from a firestore collection?

Comment: Hi, if you've found an answer to your question in the responses here, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the green check mark on the left. That way, other people will know that your question has been answered. No worries if you don't feel my answer answered your question, just wanted to let you know about the functionality. Tip: if you found a different / better way, you can always add your own answer. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 1):

It's just  a typing issue. If you change the type of `expenses` to `Observable<any[]>` your code will compile.

Basically, you told Typescript that you would be saving a plain `Array` of anything in the `expenses` property, but you are actually saving an `Observable` containing an `Array` (`Obsevable<Array<any>>` or `Observable<any[]>`).

Learn more about generic types here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html.

Comment: I've actually tried this repeatedly before, but it used to come up with another error, which made it look like adding Observable to any[] for firestore collections wasn't valid. Now I've tried it again with you suggesting this, clearly meaning I wasn't thinking wrong, and it's working.... Thanks